# Error while installing ng-bootstrap in angular 11

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have installed version (11) of angular cli and I am getting below error message when installing ng-bootstrap. can ay one please help me how to resolve this?

```
SeshagiiRaosMBP:trx-mngmt-ui-10 Munuma$ ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
Unable to find compatible package.  Using 'latest'.
Package has unmet peer dependencies. Adding the package may not succeed.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
An unhandled exception occurred: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: trx-mngmt-ui@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@11.0.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~11.0.5" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"10.0.14" from @angular/common@10.0.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~10.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/Munuma/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Munuma/.npm/_logs/2020-12-29T14_49_36_751Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
See "/private/var/folders/m1/g43nd64x54qdm_94_wk1sc7m0000gn/T/ng-fL8ZaZ/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

Answer (score 10):

Run `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps` that solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

try `npm i @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` instead of ng.
launch this command in a terminal at the root folder of your project where package.json is located

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this but still I am getting same error message. It seems like latest bootstrap is not supporting for angular 11.

Comment: trx-mngmt-ui-10 Munuma is your project folder ?

Comment: Yes Its my project folder

Comment: ok I found an issue on ng-bootstrap github repo . this is an issue with angular 11 see [this](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3897)